# Vlookup with values from another tab

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Link to my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3gH661qnZDUvP48Ubg6epuHwpDH70gANE8wW968dYg/edit?usp=sharing

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong.
I'd like to have this spreadsheet autofill data based on the selection from the drop down menu under name. In the examples tab I'd like to be able to select a name from the drop down menu and have it automatically fill in their phone numbers and emails based on the information plugged into the "Contacts" sheet.

From what I understand this can be achieved with an array formula, but I seem to be misunderstanding the application. This is the formula I've gotten to so far, was wondering if someone could outline what I'm doing wrong.

`=arrayformula(IF($E4:E8=Contacts!D4:D8, hlookup(Contacts!G4:G16,F4:F16, 1, False)))`

Comment: Welcome. Please share the spreadsheet with anyone with the link is allowed to view.

Comment: updated, my apologies

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula for your needs:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(E4:E16,Contacts!$D$4:$H$16, {4,5}, False)))
```

Functions used:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Comment: This did it, thank you!